# Поиск в файле excel в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Есть необходимость подгружать файлы xlsx, фильтровать их по ключевым словам в одном столбце, и потом выводить содержимое ячейки в другом столбце на строке где было найдено значение.

Для доступа к данным excel я решил использовать pandas, выгрузил и с помощью  .str.contains(r'\bxx') я получил данные, но как потом отфильтровать эти новые данные по True и связать для вывода необходимых данных я ни как не дойду.

Пока дошел только до этого, я просматриваю столбец, и проставляю 1 или 0, в зависимости от Treu и False.Помечая те строки которые мне будут нужны.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:/Ucheba/test.xlsx')
df["Завершена"] = np.where(df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains(r'\bтест'), 1, 0)
```

Возможно Вы подскажите более простой способ решения моей задачи.

Comment: Код приведите прямо в вопросе. А фильтровать просто: датафрейм[условие] или чтобы сразу потом взять нужный столбец: датафрейм.loc[условие, столбец]

Comment: Добавил код, и мысли которые пришли в последствии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df["Завершена"] = np.where(df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains(r'\bтест'), 1, 0)
```

Это делается проще и без привлечения `numpy`:

```py
df["Завершена"] = df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains(r'\bтест').astype(int)
```

Если вам нужно получить только те строки датафрейма, где условие истинно, то это делается так:

```py
df_selected = df[df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains(r'\bтест')]
```